# Why isn't my scrolling position working in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a sticky nav with an active state while scrolling. So when you're scrolling over each section, the nav has an active state. Kind of like what is seen here: 
https://codepen.io/rishabhp/pen/aNXVbQ

The problem I'm having is some of my numbers aren't correct. Here's the code:

```
handleScroll = () => {
    let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.deal-details__container'),
        nav = document.querySelectorAll('.overview-nav'),
        navHeight = nav[0].clientHeight;

    let totalScroll = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

        sections.forEach(section => {
            let topOffset = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            let top = topOffset - navHeight,
                bottom = top + section.clientHeight;

            if (totalScroll >= top && totalScroll <= bottom) {
                this.setState({ activeSection: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ activeSection: false });
            }
        });
    });
    console.log(totalScroll);
};
```

For instance my totalScroll inside of the forEach only amounts to -20 or something similar.

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try using `scrollTop` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) instead of `getBoundingClientRect().top`?

Comment: I have. I found that `getBoundingClientRect().top` works in this situation. `scrollTop` just hasn't been reliable.I get errors that it's not a function.

Comment: It's not a function, it's a property of the element. So it should be called like `elem.scrollTop` instead of `elem.scrollTop()`.